Вызов функции после загрузки нескольких фото Telebot
Я новичок. Есть код, который сохраняет фото, отправленные пользователем в бот:
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def handle_photos(message):
    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_datetime = str(current_datetime).split()
    current_datetime = '.'.join(current_datetime)
    current_datetime = current_datetime.split(":")
    current_datetime = '.'.join(current_datetime)

    photo = message.photo[-1]
    file_info = bot.get_file(photo.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    photo_name = f"{current_datetime}"
    save_path = f'../data/img/{photo_name}.jpg'
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)


Я так понимаю, что хендлер будет выполняться ровно столько раз, сколько фото в сообщении пользователя. Вне зависимости от того, сколько изображений в сообщении отправит пользователь (а их количество заранее неизвестно), мне нужно после их сохранения вызвать функцию, например send_email(), которая отправит загруженные сообщения по почте.
Как это красиво сделать - вызвать функцию send_email() только после того, как все фото будут сохранены?

Форматировать дату можно в одну строку. Получение и форматирование: current_time = datetime.now()
formatted_time = current_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d.%H.%M.%S.%f')

И из библиотеки можно импортировать только необходимое и не придётся вызывать каждый раз метод через точку: from datetime import datetime

Спасибо, исправим.

А как вы узнаете что все фото получили?)

В том и дело, что никак. Я надеялся, что когда пользователь отправляет боту несколько фото одним сообщением, количество фото содержится в неком идентификаторе. Но, как оказалось, каждое фото обрабатывается хендлером как отдельное сообщение. Вероятно, решение - это добавить кнопку "загрузил всё" для пользователя.

@Oleg_Py или отправлять самостоятельно через небольшую задержку. Но думаю кнопка это определённо лучшее решение. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1582658/562052

Посмотрел ссылку. Интересно, а можно ли принять в функцию под декоратором  @bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo']) аргументом не message, а media_group? Тогда бы мы узнали сколько фото нам отправил пользователь.
